# Get set of all nodes, which are referenced by descendant, but are not descendants themself

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm searching for a *reusable* way to get all nodes from a xml document, which are referenced (via id) from descendant of a given node, but which are not descendants of the given node themselves. For example:

```
<root>
  <somenode>
     <a id="a1"/>
     <aref ref="a1"/>
  </somenode>
  <somenode>
     <a id="a2"/>
     <aref ref="a1"/>
     <aref ref="a2"/>
  </somenode>
</root>
```

If the given node would be /root/somenode[1], the resulting nodeset should be empty. Every referenced a is a child of /root/somenode[1]. On the other hand, if the given node would be /root/somenode[2], the resulting nodeset should contain /root/somenode[1]/a[1] and nothing else.

It is important that the resulting nodeset is always sorted in the same way. Also a solution should only use xslt-1.0 and the exlst extensions build into xsltproc (exact versions of the libraries: "Using libxml 20708, libxslt 10126 and libexslt 815")

Thanks in advance,
Jost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.exslt.org/set/functions/difference/index.html, libxslt supports that function so doing

```
<xsl:key name="el-by-id" match="*" use="id"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:variable name="refs" select="set:difference(key('el-by-id', descendant::*/@ref), descendant::*)"/>
```

should do (with `xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"`) in a template which your node as the context node.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided here **don't use any extension functions** and are 100% portable on any XSLT processor.

**Using the xslt function `generate-id()`:**

```
//*[@id = /*/somenode[1]/aref/@ref 
  and 
    not(generate-id(ancestor::somenode) = generate-id(/*/somenode[1]))
   ]
```

Use of keys may bring more efficiency,

**This is also possible to express as a single XPath 1.0 expression** using the Kayessian formula for node-set intersection:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

**In pure XPath 2.0 one will use the `is` operator instead of `generate-id()`.**

**Here is a complete demo**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  "<xsl:copy-of select=
   "//*[@id = /*/somenode[1]/aref/@ref
      and
        not(generate-id(ancestor::somenode) = generate-id(/*/somenode[1]))
       ]"/>"
============
  "<xsl:copy-of select=
   "//*[@id = /*/somenode[2]/aref/@ref
      and
        not(generate-id(ancestor::somenode) = generate-id(/*/somenode[2]))
        ]"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
  <somenode>
     <a id="a1"/>
     <aref ref="a1"/>
  </somenode>
  <somenode>
     <a id="a2"/>
     <aref ref="a1"/>
     <aref ref="a2"/>
  </somenode>
</root>
```

**the XPath expressions are evaluated and the selected nodes are copied to the output:**

```
  ""
============
  "<a id="a1" />"
```